# Using blowfish in CBC mode for encryption and decryption but how to proceed with the IV?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have a UI to add/edit password .These passwords are encrypted using Blowfish in CBC mode and it worked fine but during decryption it required a IV (it threw a parameter missing exception.)

I have used the cipher class while initiating the cipher so this would have taken care of the IV while encrypting.

So my doubt is,

1. should the IV be same for both encryption and decryption? I read on some pages that while decryption if we use an incorrect IV the first block will be incorrect but the remaining blocks would be correct .Can you explain on this?
2. IF the IV (in case of encryption and decryption using the same IV) be saved should it be saved as a plain object or encrypted along with the password using some delimiter ?Which will be safer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the IV should be the same for encryption/decryption. In CBC, if I recall properly, errors will cascade down the blocks. So the whole message will be wrong if you use the wrong IV.
2. The IV can be stored in plaintext. If you try and store it encrypted, you'll end up needing to store the IV used to encrypt the IV...

However, it is generally considered a bad practice to store passwords in an encrypted form. If someone were to retrieve you database, they'd only need to find one key to retrieve all the passwords.

The recommended way to store passwords is to use a hash function multiple times, also known as a PBKDF (password based key derivation function), either based on a plain hash or on a hmac function. See the [OWASP password storage cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Impose_infeasible_verification_on_attacker).

There are primitives for this in java, see [the example on this page](http://adambard.com/blog/3-wrong-ways-to-store-a-password). (Search for Use a Password Hashing Algorithm and scroll down to the java implementation.)

Comment: Errors will not propagate as the preceding ciphertext is xored with the plaintext before encryption and you have the complete ciphertext. Only the first block will be corrupted.

Comment: No problem. I always remember this because you cannot implement a CBC bit flipping attack without this particular property.